# Uncaught Symfony "cannot rename" causing Critical Error on Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, error, issues, filesystem

I got a Critical Error today which has caused the backend of the website to be inaccessible. Is there a way to fix this? and is there a way to stop this from happening?

An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 289 of the file /nas/content/live/icadev21/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php. Error message: Uncaught Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Exception\IOException: Cannot rename "/nas/content/live/icadev21/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedCiviContainer.38f8e379763eb3410e8abbe75dff0d3c.phpk3pMie" to "/nas/content/live/icadev21/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/templates_c/CachedCiviContainer.38f8e379763eb3410e8abbe75dff0d3c.php". in /nas/content/live/icadev21/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php:289

Stack trace:

```
#0 /nas/content/live/icadev21/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/filesystem/Filesystem.php(694): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->rename('/nas/content/li...', '/nas/content/li...', true)
#1 /nas/content/live/icadev21/wp-content/plugins/civicrm/civicrm/vendor/symfony/config/ResourceCheckerConfigCache.php(124): Symfony\Component\Filesystem\Filesystem->dumpFile('/nas/content/li...', '
```

Site Specs:
WordPress version 5.7.2
Current theme: Avada (version 6.2.3)
Current plugin: CiviCRM (version 5.38.0)
PHP version 7.4.18

I'm not an expert coder but have access to FTP files to make changes. I could use all the help I can get. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE!  The error is about renaming files which suggests a permissions problem.  Check the permissions on the templates_c folder and remove all the existing files in there (they will be recreated automatically).

Is this a new site?  If so, how did you do the installation?  Permissions should normally be taken care of by the installation process.

Comment: Thank you for the help! This is a new install. I installed via FTP and I will note that the "CiviCRM installer" did not popup when I activated the plugin from the Wordpress backend on my site but I went through the system status and configuration checklist in the CiviCRM > Admin Console. I am hosting on WPEngine if that helps.
File permissions on the templates_c folder are now set to full access numeric value 777 via FTP and so far I haven't seen that error come up again (been a few hours) and I'm able to access the backend of the site again.

Comment: Unfortunately, the same error is back. Is there somewhere else I should be changing permissions for that folder other than FTP?

Comment: Does the templates_c directory and all the files in it have the same owner?